# Deploy Logic App to different tenant fails with LinkedAuthorizationFailed error

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-logic-apps

I would like to deploy a Logic App from VS 2017 into another tenants subscription. I am the owner of the target resource group but I am still getting the LinkedAuthorizationFailed error when using the deploy functionally within VS2017.

```
10:40:41 - "error": {
10:40:41 -     "code": "LinkedAuthorizationFailed",
10:40:41 -     "message": "The client has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/listSecrets/action' on scope '/subscriptions/XXXX/resourcegroups/XXXX/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/LogicappName', however the current tenant 'XXXX' is not authorized to access linked subscription 'XXXX'."
10:40:41 -   }
```

I can create and manage logic apps via the web portal. But it should also be somehow possible to deploy via VS or?

I was a co admin before and I thing it worked than, but I can't expect the client to make me a co admin just to deploy Logic Apps.

Comment: I do have the same error created a ticket for Azure support service. If I get something solid will definitely share. I am using a service principal account in my own Azure subs.

Answer (score 1):

This error is not related to the permissions to deploy a Logic App , but to get the keys of an Azure Function that is being called within the Logic App. You need to check that you have the correct permissions not only to deploy onto the resource group you want to, but also to get the keys from the Azure Function you are calling from the Logic App.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a wrong azure function linked within the logic app.
After fixing the wrong subscription i linked there the error went away.